# How to call a universal service/provider angular

Tags: angularjs

I need a factory to be called when angular is ran, no matter what controller it starts on.  The purpose of it is for config variables.

What ways could I have this happen?

Comment: Angular.Module has a `run` function for stuff that needs to be done at startup, see docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#config

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted, thanks a lot man :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger code that needs to be run once the application is loaded, hook into the `run` function that is available on `Angular.Module` ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#config))

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.run(function() {
    //stuff goes here
});
```

That code will get run once all modules are loaded, and as a result you can inject dependencies into it as well.

If your config variables are static, however, you could use `value` ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#service)) as well.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.value('myConfig', {
    foo: 'bar'
});
```

`myConfig` can then be injected into controllers or services just like any other dependency.